# use specific compiler with MINGW

Tags: mingw, mingw32

I have an old project which i want to compile with the 4.1.2 version of GCC and G++. i have them downloaded, but i don't know how to give it to the MINGW to use them as default c/c++ compilers. 
Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you downloaded the whole package (gcc, binutils, runtime, win32api) from one release of MinGW (not required, but ensures compatibility), you can extract them some folder on your hard drive, say

```
C:\oldmingw
```

So that `C:\oldingw\bin` contains a `gcc.exe`.

Open a command prompt (type `cmd.exe` in the Vista/7 Orb search box or in the Windows "Run Command" dialog). Type

```
set PATH=C:\oldming\bin;%PATH%
```

Run

```
gcc -v
```

And ensure that the version reported is 4.1.2.

On linux, same thing, but the directory will be different, and your command to set PATH will be:

```
export PATH=/path/to/oldmingw:$PATH
```